# How to completely uninstall/remove Sprockets/asset pipeline in a Rails 6 project using webpack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I recently made the transition from Sprockets to Webpack, and now I'm loading every asset (javascripts, stylesheets, images, font, etc.) in my app through the latter. I'm now looking forward to completely remove sprockets and every sprocket-related gem, file, helper, etc. from my app, as I feel it's become redundant.
**What are the steps I should take in order to do so?**

So far, I've only managed to remove the `sass-rails gem` from my `Gemfile` (which admitedly hasn't taken me too far...), but the sprockets gem is still loaded in my `Gemfile.lock`, since it's called by nothing than the Rails gem (I didn't generate my app with the `--skip-sprockets` flag), and also generators create assets when I invoke them.

**Looking for advice in order to completely and safely remove it from my system.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 6.0.2.2, the rails gem declares a dependency on the sprockets-rails gem, so you're not going to be able to remove the sprockets gem at this time. Removing that forced dependency sounds like a good change for a future version of Rails, but if I had to guess, that sounds more like Rails 7 than 6.x.